# Funcion jquery solo pasa una vez

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

dispongo de la siguiente minifuncion en jquery:

```
var clicked = false;
    $('#pannelClick').on('click', function () {
        if (!clicked) {
            $('.is-contact-card').css({marginRight: "0"});
            clicked = true;
        } else {
            $('.is-contact-card').css({marginRight: "-440px"});
            clicked = true;
        }
    });
```

El problema que tengo (y me pasa a menudo), es que no se como hacer que la funcion pase mas de una vez. Es algo que todavia no termino de pillar. Alguien seria tan amable de explicar que es lo que me falla?
gracias

Comment: No te entiendo, esa funcion hace que cuando hagas click en el elemento con el id pannelclick te quita el pone el margen a 0 y da el valor true a la variable clicked, entoces la siguiente vez que va a entrar clicked esta true y le aplica marginright : -440px, la siguiente vez sigue estando true asique vuelve a ponerle -440 y así cada vez que hagas click sin regargar la pagina

Comment: Si lo que quieres hacer es un `toggle` o interruptor, deberia de poner la variable `clicked=true` en el `if` pero cambiarla a false en el `else`, ahora mismo en los dos caminos se pone a true, por lo que en cuanto clickas una vez ya no volvera a entrar en el `if`.

Comment: No entiendo, ¿por qué los dos ponen la variable en `true`? ¿No se supone que cuando entra al `else` debería ponerse a `false`?

Answer (score 0):

Perdonad esta pregunta tan bàsica, estoy aprendiendo de manera autodicta todo y es bastante para mi. 
Como vosotros habeis dicho, la solucion es solamentre cambiar en `else` a `false`

```
var clicked = false;
$('#pannelClick').on('click', function () {
    if (!clicked) {
        $('.is-contact-card').css({marginRight: "0"});
        clicked = true;
    } else {
        $('.is-contact-card').css({marginRight: "-440px"});
        clicked = false;
    }
});
```